# how to provide credentials in apache beam python programmatically?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, airflow, apache-beam

We are using apache beam through airflow. Default GCS account is set with environmental variable - GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS. We don't want to change environmental variable as it might affect other processes running at that time. I couldn't find a way to change Google Cloud Dataflow Service Account programmatically. 
We are creating pipeline in following way
p = beam.Pipeline(argv=self.conf)

Is there any option through argv or options, where in I can mention the location of gcs credential file?
Searched through documentation, but didn't find much information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can specify a service account when you launch the job with a basic flag:
`--serviceAccount=my-service-account-name@my-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com`

That account will need the `Dataflow Worker` role attached plus whatever else you would like(GCS/BQ/Etc). [Details here](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/concepts/security-and-permissions#controller-service-account). You don't need the SA to be stored in GCS, or keys locally to use it.